# How to transform query results?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I need transform string query to int to be evaluated. I'm going well or exists another way to do that?

This is a extract to the code. Is it possible to transform the result, or is not?

Code:

```
string query = "SELECT Movie.Code FROM Movie WHERE Movie.Code = @code";

int i = 0;
i = int.Parse(query);

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        string R1 = "OK";

        if (sdr.Read())
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                Re1 =  "OK";
            }
            else
            {
                 Re1 = "Fail";
            }
        }

        return Re1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What should be the value of `i`?  I don't saw declaration of variable `Re1`;

Comment: You really need to read up on what `int.Parse` does, because it's definitely not what you want... It's also very unclear what you want that value to mean. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: It looks like you are passing the query to int.Parse() and expecting it to return the query result?  If so this is an extreme conceptual error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I can only guess but it looks like you are trying to set the value of the `@code`parameter. Look into [SqlParameterCollection.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads)

Comment: i is the result of a query and Re1 yes it is but commented, I will edit the post. Im trying if the records of that query is more than 0 return ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in the *existence* of (a single) record(s) you can just query the `count` and [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(Movie.Code) FROM Movie WHERE Movie.Code = @code";

int i = 0;

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();

    i = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if(i > 0)
    {
        // OK
    }
    else
    {
        // Fail
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse the query before it actually retrieves a result.

`i = int.Parse(query);`

You can do something like this to read the results of the `cmd.ExecuteReader()` command.

```
if (reader.HasRows) {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           if (reader.GetInt32(0) > 0)
           {
              Re1 =  "OK";
           }
           else {
              Re1 = "Fail";
           }
        }
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
    }
```

Comment: oh thanks,  ill  try . is the only way to do that ? thanks again

Comment: Of course it isn't the only way to do that, read [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader) or search for things on google like *"How to **retrieve data** in **sql** using **c#**"*.